# How to built a dynamic string PLSQL

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

I have 2 associative_arrays of number and I am trying to built a dynamic string for a dynamic query.

This is my for statement:

```
    for indx_opt in 1..IDOPTarray.count loop

         IF indx_opt=1 AND IDFGCFCParray.count=1 THEN
         sql_stmt_2:=sql_stmt_2||' and wopt.id_ft_opt = ';
         sql_stmt_2:=sql_stmt_2|| (IDOPTarray(indx_opt));
         end if;

         if indx_opt=1  AND  IDFGCFCParray.count>1 then
         sql_stmt_2:=sql_stmt_2||' and wopt.id_ft_opt in(';
         sql_stmt_2:=sql_stmt_2||(IDOPTarray(indx_opt));

         elsif indx_opt>=1 AND IDFGCFCParray.count>=0 then
         sql_stmt_2:=sql_stmt_2||','||(IDOPTarray(indx_opt))||')';
```

With 2 number in IDOPTarray I get a correct result:

```
    and wopt.id_ft_opt in(27,28)
```

Instead with more then 2 number in IDOPTarray I get this result:

```
    ,17228),17229),17230)
```

What I want to get is this:

```
     where w.id = 303 and wopt.id_ft_opt in (17228,17229,17230)
```

if I have 5 numbers, I want to get this for the 'where' clause:

```
     where w.id = 321 and wopt.id_ft_opt in (17228,17229,17230,17231,17232)
```

I want a dynamic output of my string.

IDFGCFCParray is the 2nd array, but is not important right now in order to get the output I want.

Does somebody can help me? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close bracket only if indx_opt is equil to IDOPTarray.count. 
And simple example.

```
declare 
 type  list_number is table of number;
  xx list_number := new list_number(1,2,3,5,7,8);
  str varchar2(4000);
begin 

 for i in xx.first .. xx.last loop
  if i = 1 then 
    str := ' condition in ('||xx(i);
  else 
    str := str||','||xx(i);
  end if;

   if i = xx.last then 
   str := str||')';
   end if; 
 end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(str);
end;
```

If you colleciton is sql levle type you can do this in this way

```
declare 
  xx list_number := new list_number(1,2,3,5,7,8);
  str varchar2(4000);
begin 
 SELECT  'condition in ('||LISTAGG(column_value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_value)||')' into str from table(xx);
 dbms_output.put_line(str); 
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution. For the moment I think I just solve the issue by modifying the if condition